# UITableView with SearchView makes new cells overlap old ones on search

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uisearchbar, uitableview

Iam implementing a SearchView to filter the data in my UITableView. Iam able to search successfully, the only issue is when the UITableView data gets filtered, the old cells still exist and the filtered ones overlap them giving me a messy output. I have cleared the Table source as suggested by my answers on SO, but still not resolved the problem.

Here is what Iam trying to do:

FilterController

void searchFiler_TextChanged(object sender, UISearchBarTextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.SearchText))
    {
        ppTable.Source = null;
        AppDelegate.filteredList = null;

        ppTable.ReloadData();
        filteredModelList = filter(dupes, e.SearchText);
        mAdapter = new PeoplePlacesSource(filteredModelList, "");
        ppTable.Source = mAdapter;
        ppTable.ReloadData();
    }
    else
    {
        ppTable.Source = null;
        mAdapter = new PeoplePlacesSource(dupes, "");
        searchFiler.TextChanged += searchFiler_TextChanged;
        mAdapter.TableRowSelected += mAdapter_TableRowSelected;
        ppTable.Source = mAdapter;
        ppTable.ReloadData();
    }
}
```

PeoplePlacesSource

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {


            cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("PeoplePlacesCell_Cell") as PeoplePlacesCell ?? PeoplePlacesCell.Create();
subList = userList.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);



            cell.UpdatePeoplePlacesCell(subList);
             return cell;

        }
```

PeoplePlacesCell

```
 internal void UpdatePeoplePlacesCell(System.Linq.IGrouping<string, Models.EmployeeModel> subList)
    {
        var yPosition =15;
        var xPosition = 10;

        var imgDefault = new UIImageView();
        imgDefault.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(10, viewParent.Frame.Y, 60,60);
        imgDefault.Image = UIImage.FromFile("ic_appicon.png");
        CALayer profileImageCircle = imgDefault.Layer;
        profileImageCircle.CornerRadius = 28;
        profileImageCircle.BorderWidth = 2;
        profileImageCircle.BorderColor = new CoreGraphics.CGColor(211, 34, 41);
        profileImageCircle.MasksToBounds = true;
        imgDefault.ClipsToBounds = true;
        viewParent.AddSubview(imgDefault);


        var labelUserName = new UILabel();
        labelUserName.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, viewContainer.Frame.Width, 30);
        labelUserName.TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB(211, 34, 41);
        labelUserName.Text = subList.Key ;
        labelUserName.ClipsToBounds = true;

        labelUserName.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(17);
        viewContainer.AddSubview(labelUserName);



        var mList = subList.Take(5);
        foreach (var employeeModel in mList)
        {
            var labelPlace = new UILabel();
            labelPlace.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, yPosition, viewContainer.Frame.Width, 50);

            if (employeeModel.Place.Contains(","))
            {
                labelPlace.Text = employeeModel.Place.Substring(0, employeeModel.Place.IndexOf(","));
            }
            else
            {
                labelPlace.Text = employeeModel.Place;
            }
            labelPlace.Font = UIFont.FromName(labelPlace.Font.Name, 12f);
            labelUserName.SizeToFit();
                labelPlace.ClipsToBounds = true;
            viewContainer.AddSubview(labelPlace);



           yPosition += 15;




        }
    }
```

How can I solve this? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the same problem after scroll? You cells are reused, but I don't see code for removing added subviews. Try to remove all subviews you added, before reusing cells.